# TypeError: interaction.options.getString is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am making a command to enable and disable events and when choosing any options it returns

`TypeError: interaction.options.getString is not a function`

I dont know why it does this as ive used `interaction.options.getString` before like how i did below and it works fine

Code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'settings',
    description: 'Toggle Certain Functions',
    timeout: 5000,
    category: 'general',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'action',
            description: 'Action to perform',
            type: 3,
            required: true,
            choices: [
                {
                    name: 'show',
                    value: 'action_show',
                },
                {
                    name: 'enable',
                    value: 'action_enable',
                },
                {
                    name: 'disable',
                    value: 'action_disable',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'module',
            description: 'Module to toggle',
            type: 3,
            required: true,
            choices: [
                {
                    name: 'all',
                    value: 'module_all',
                },
                {
                    name: 'premium',
                    value: 'module_starboard',
                },
                {
                    name: 'logging',
                    value: 'module_logging',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],

    run: async (client, interaction) => {
        const actions = interaction.options.getString('action');
        const modules = interaction.options.getString('module');

        if (actions === action_show) {
            if (modules === module_all) {
        // CODE
```

Comment: Can you make sure that `interaction` is a `CommandInteraction` and not other types of interaction (eg. `ButtonInteraction`)

Comment: im using the same format for my other commands and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

What version of DiscordJS are you on? Some older versions use different options systems.

You can update your version by running:

```
npm i discord.js@latest
```

or

```
yarn upgrade discord.js
```

Comment: im on discordjs  v13.6.0 and all my other slash commands using the same format work fine

Comment: What do you get when you log `interaction.options`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BJSqLgjh